# Calculus - Functions

Tags: functions

How do I go about this question? Also how exactly will its graph be?

$$ f(x) = 1 + 4x -x^2 $$

$$g(x) = \begin{cases} 
\max f(t) & x \le t \le (x+1) ;\quad 0 \le x < 3 \\
\min (x+3) & 3 \le x \le 5
\end{cases}
$$

Verify continuity of $g(x)$ for all $x$ in $[0,5]$

Comment: How much work of your own have you done here so far?

Comment: http://meta.matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/93/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Well, actually I don't know what to do about the "max" and "min" part, apart from that, I've drawn the graph of the function ignoring the "max" and "min" conditions. I only need help with tackling those terms

Comment: For one, why would that $\;\max\,,\,\,\min\;$ exist at all? Can you quote some theorem that'll help you here?

Comment: The definition you gave for $g(x)$ is no function definition as far as I see. Please make it precise.

Comment: That's how the question was stated.
What I'm confused in is what to compare, usually max contains 2 functions to compare and choose the max value from, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is a way to think of solving this problem geometrically. note that $1 + 4x - x^2$ is a parabola symmetric about $x = 2,$ opens downward, a has a local max at $x = 2, y = 5.$ think of the function $g$ as the global max on the moving window $x, x+1]$ of length $1.$ for $0 \le x \le 1,$ this max occurs at the right end point 
$x + 1$ and the value is $f(x+1).$ for $1 \le x \le 2,$ the global max is at $x = 2$ and the value is $f(2)$ and finally for $2 \le x \le 3,$ the global max occurs at the left end point $x$ and the value is $f(x).$ we can write this as piecewise function 
$g(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll} f(x+1) & if 0 \le x \le 1 \cr
                                  f(2)   & if 1 \le x \le 2 \cr
                                  f(x)   & if 2 \le x \le 3 \cr
                                  x + 1  & if 3 \le x \end{array} \right.$

you can verify the continuity of $g$ at the boundary points $1, 2, $ and $3.$