# If $f(x)=1+4x-x^2$ $\;\forall \; \;x \in R$

Tags: functions, derivatives, continuity

If $f(x)=1+4x-x^2$ $\;\forall \; \;x \in R$

$g(x)=\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  \max f(t); \;x\leq t\leq x+1; \;0\leq x \lt3 \\
  {6}; \; \mbox{if }  3\leq x\leq 5
 \end{array}
\right.$

Verify Continuity of $g(x)$, for all $x \in [0,5]$

**My Approach:**

$f(t)=1+4t-t^2$

$f'(t)=4-2t$

$\implies$ $f(t)$ will be maximum at $t=2$.

since, $g(x)=\max \ f(t)$ $\;$ for $t \in [x,x+1], 0\leq x \lt 3$

$\implies$
$g(x)=f(x+1) $ $\;$ for $x+1 \lt 2 $$\;$ i.e. $x \in[0,1)$

But how do i approach for $x \in [1,3)$.

**Below given is the link to the same question asked earlier but I did not understand the explanation for $x \in [1,3)$**

**Is there any simpler way to do further?**

[Calculus - Functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1041189/calculus-functions)

Comment: what does $\min\;(x+3)$ mean?

Comment: min of $(x+3)$ $\forall x \in [3,5]$ that is $6$

Comment: but it is just dependent on the value of $x$ right? so $g(x)=\min\; (x+3)$ doesn't make sense to me as there is only one value for every $x \in [3,5]$. For example $g(4)=\min\; (4+3)$ doesn't seem to convey the idea properly.

Comment: I've edited the question.